# Form submit in IE11 doesn't work correctly

Tags: javascript, html, forms, internet-explorer, onsubmit

I have a problem with the form onsubmit function in IE 11.
When the submit button was triggered, the "doSomething()"-function will be called. Inside the "doSomething()" function I call another function that does some input-validation stuff. This function always returns false but sets a flag to true if all validation errors are gone. If the flag was set to true, the "doSomething()"-function returns true and the form will be submitted and the action is called. This pattern works in Firefox, Chrome and Safari but doesn't in IE11. In IE it calls the action before the "doSomeValidation()"-Function is ready. :-/ Can anybody help me out here? Thanks a lot!!!

```
<form action="headToNextPage.php" onsubmit="return doSomething()">
```

js

```
flag = false, // a global flag inside the js-script

function doSomeValidation(){
// validate the inputs and set "flag" to true if all errors are gone
}

function doSomething(){
   doSomeValidation(); // do the validation stuff

   if(flag==true) {
   // do some other stuff
     return true
   }

   return false;
}
```

Comment: Try `console.log(window.flag,flag)` where you use it and see if you get what you think. ALSO return flag instead of true or false:
`function doSomething(){
   doSomeValidation(); return flag;}`

Comment: Can't you use a little bit of html5 constraint validation? Almost no js is required... Can you show us the full html form?

Comment: maybe some asynchronous call in doSomeValidation

Comment: unfortunately, I can't show you the whole form because it's work related... that's the reason why I need to work with IE because it's companies standard browser. -_- I need a custom validation with showing css-styled messages and icons and stuff that's why i did it this way (with JS)...

Comment: @Mahi ... you mean with "promise"?

Comment: yeah something like `setInterval`,`settimeout`

Comment: @mplungjan the flag is false and it doesn't call the rest of the "doSomething()" function

Comment: @Mahi well, it's the last way because it's kinda dirty i think ;)

Answer (score 0):

Replace comma after false to semi colon and add some alert inside the dosomething method its works in IE11 surely
`flag = false;`

Comment: sorry, there is a semicolon normally... i mistyped in my post

Comment: did u try with alert

Comment: yes i did... all alerts after calling the doSomeValidation() function won't get called

Comment: I don't have it here, because I'm currently not at work. I can do it tomorrow

Comment: check whether any debugging error by pressing F12 key and verify any code is blocked in middle.

Comment: yes i did. And it helped! Thanks sehe my comment below

Comment: I put Alerts in different parts of the doSomeValidation function and narrowed down the problematic Code

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. Problem was, that I called the JS .startsWith(..)-function on a string inside of the jQuery $( document ).ready(..)-function. Chrome, Firefox and Safari ignored it, but IE went crazy with it but didn't show any errors. I took the .indexOf(..)-function instead and it worked. thanks to all for helping me out here!